# Put different stroke color and width on some circles markers on jVectorMap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jvectormap

I'm creating a map with jVectorMap. I drew circles on it to represent earthquakes thanks to geo coordinates lat/lng, like this:

```
markers: [
     {"latLng":[33.428,-116.4253333],"name":"19km NNW of Borrego Springs, California","mag":3.37,"depth":13.9},
     {"latLng":[33.5046667,-116.507],"name":"16km ESE of Anza, California","mag":3.22,"depth":15.44},
     {"latLng":[40.8905,-111.6832],"name":"16km E of Cennterville, Utah","mag":3.3,"depth":11.9},
     {"latLng":[36.7621,-98.0439],"name":"27km E of Cherokee, Oklahoma","mag":3.2,"depth":11.68}
]
```

I would like to put a bigger stroke-width and a different stroke-color to some of those circles.. For example to the circles with lat/lng 
[40.8905,-111.6832],[36.7621,-98.0439].

Here's the [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/__sre/dvLzsLrd/2/) of the map.

Is there a way to do so? I've been trying lots of things but none seem to work and similar questions have no answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not be the best solution but a simple option to get it done without getting your hands too dirty could be using CSS.

```
.jvectormap-marker:nth-child(9){
   stroke-width: 20;
   stroke: red;
   fill: #FFFF00;
}

.jvectormap-marker:nth-child(10){
   stroke: #00FFFF;
}
```

Updated fiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/ozke/dvLzsLrd/3/

Comment: It works, but I was looking for a solution where I can choose the circle markers by their lat/lng coordinates. Thanks very much anyway.